# How to get javascript mouseover to highlight other elements in an svg file (context change)

Tags: javascript, css, svg, hover

I'm trying to solve a very simple problem: two elements; a button and a rectangle. When you hover over the button, the rectangle changes fill colour. I've tried CSS, but for some reason i can't get the '*className*:hover *targetClass*{}' to work. 
The main body is from Visio, and i've tried to edit it (*Edit:removed visio metadata):

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events" 
width="8.26772in" height="11.6929in" viewBox="0 0 595.276 841.89" xml:space="preserve" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" class="st3">

    <style type="text/css">
    <![CDATA[

        .st1 {fill:#5b9bd5;stroke:#ffffff;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-width:0.5}
        .st2 {fill:#ffffff;font-family:Calibri;font-size:0.833336em}
        .st3 {fill:#FFFF00;fill-rule:evenodd;font-size:12px;overflow:visible;stroke-linecap:square;stroke-miterlimit:3}
        .button {fill:#5b9bd5;stroke:#ffffff;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-width:0.5}
        .button:hover{fill: #FFFF00;}
    ]]>
    </style>

 <g id="ThePage">   
    <title>Page-1</title>

    <g id="shape2" transform="translate(283.465,-531.496)">
        <title>Multi-Attachment rectangle.2</title>
        <desc>Button text</desc>
        <rect x="0" y="799.37" width="56.6929" height="42.5197" class="button"/>
        <text x="5.25" y="823.63" class="st2" >Button text</text>   
    </g>

    <g id="shape1" transform="translate(255.118,-595.276)">
        <title>Multi-Attachment rectangle</title>
        <desc>Big box text</desc>
        <rect x="0" y="756.85" width="113.386" height="85.0394" class="st1"/>
        <text x="32.78" y="802.37" class="st2" >Big box text</text>     
    </g>
 </g>

</svg>
```

My javascript code that I tried to implement but failed was:

```
var javaButton = document.getElementsByClassName('button');

for (var i = 0; i < javaButton.length; i++) {
    javaButton[i].addEventListener('mouseover', mouseOverEffect);
    javaButton[i].addEventListener('mouseout', mouseOutEffect);
}

function mouseOverEffect() {
    this.classList.add("rect-highlight");
}

function mouseOutEffect() {
    this.classList.remove("rect-highlight");
}
```

Where "rect-highlight" is in the CSS part of the svg as: .rect-highlight {fill: #ec008c;}. 
I know this works, as the button changed colour if  I hover over it, however need to get the context from "this" to another element. How do I do that?

*Edit: removed visio metadata

**Edit : added code body

***Edit: added code fences so markdown doesn't eat my code.

Comment: Could you provide HTML/SVG etc. and CSS?

Comment: Have you tried inserting a `<style>` block into your SVG (it is HTML after all)? `mouseover` is like `:hover` in CSS. So `path:hover {...}`, `#myPath {...}` or `circle:hover {...}`, etc. should work fine. Not every problem needs a JS solution.

Comment: Sorry! My first post, I've added the main body of the code. If I remove the target class, the hover works for the box that is selected. But I can't get it to work on another element.

Comment: Narik, you really need to post the full SVG (all code including `<svg>...</svg>`). The HTML and CSS you are working on too. The code you posted runs into errors and displays nothing. Please read how to post a [reprex]. Really want to help out, but need code that works. There is all kind of Visio code in you SVG, this may give you problems too. I will need to check that... Regular SVG has nothing with `<v:..` inside, this is Visio specific.

Comment: Can you export to 'standard SVG/HTML'  from Viso and post that code? Other programs (like Inkscape) have that option.

Comment: Hi Rene, I'm slowly getting the hang of it, I've removed the metadata so it should be easier to understand, and the entire code block should be there now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to fiddle around with this, because I have an interest in doing cool things with SVG exported from Visio. There may be more elegant ways to solve your problem, as suggested and demonstrated by the other posters, but perhaps my attempt will be helpful anyway.

I've created a jsFiddle that does what you want, I think. Have a look:
https://jsfiddle.net/visioguy/nv3ew0fh/

First, I made a few changes to your the <svg> code:

1. I gave the top-most the <g> an id="ThePage", so that I could avoid it in the js code.
2. I set class="button" on the the <g> that contains the rectangle, rather than at the "sub-level" rectangle, where you had it.
3. I added pointer-events="none" to the  elements inside the button shape's group. When you mouse-over the <text> element it caused mouseout to fire, even though the cursor was still within the group. This pointer-events setting stops that behavior, but now you can't select/copy the text. That might be just fine.
4. There are a few styles in a separate CSS area in the jsFiddle.

Here are the CSS style additions:

```
/* 
Make the SVG big enough to see and give
it a subtle color: 
*/
svg {
  background: whitesmoke;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}

/* 
Highlight direct <rect> children of any <g>
that has this class: 
*/
.rect-highlight > rect {
  fill: red;
}
```

And here is the javaScript. I used querySelectorAll to find shapes according to CSS rules. If you add other non-button boxes to your <svg>, this code will find them and highlight them:

```
// Select all <g> elements that are classed as 'button':
let buttonShapes = document.querySelectorAll('.button');
console.log("buttonShapes: ", buttonShapes.length);

// Add the event handlers to all of these button shapes:
for(let buttonShape of buttonShapes) {
    buttonShape.addEventListener('mouseenter', mouseEnterEffect);
    buttonShape.addEventListener('mouseout'  , mouseOutEffect);
}

function mouseEnterEffect(){

    // Select all other <g> in the SVG that are not classed as button
    // and are not id'd as ThePage:
    let otherShapes = document.querySelectorAll('g:not(.button):not(#ThePage)');
    console.log("otherShapes:", otherShapes.length); 

    for(let g of otherShapes) {
        g.classList.add("rect-highlight");
    }

}

function mouseOutEffect(){

    // Select all shapes that are groups <g> and are classed
    // with "rect-highlight":
    let highlightShapes = document.querySelectorAll('g.rect-highlight');
    console.log("highlightShapes:", highlightShapes.length); 

    for(let g of highlightShapes) {
        g.classList.remove("rect-highlight");
    }  

}
```

One last note: you can remove all of the extra elements and attributes that Visio adds. Essentially anything that starts with "v:". This is meta data that Visio can read if you decide to re-import the svg into Visio at a later time. Things like Shape Data fields, User-defined cells, layers, text-formatting and other info is stored in these tags.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what your issue is, since you did not provide a sample SVG, but if you want to highlight related elements you can use a `:hover` selector.

You can get the previous and next sibling of the current element by accessing `previousElementSibling` and `nextElementSibling` respectively.

```js
const showSiblings = (e) => toggleSiblings(e.target, true);
const resetSiblings = (e) => toggleSiblings(e.target, false);

Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.box')).forEach(box => {
  box.addEventListener('mouseenter', showSiblings);
  box.addEventListener('mouseleave', resetSiblings);
});

function toggleSiblings(curr, visible) {
  let prev = curr.previousElementSibling;
  let next = curr.nextElementSibling;
  if (prev) {
    prev.classList.toggle('sib-prev', visible);
  }
  if (next) {
    next.classList.toggle('sib-next', visible);
  }
}
```

```css
svg { background: #FF7F7F; }

.box { stroke-width: 4; cursor: pointer; }

.foo { fill: #4C4C7F; stroke: #00007F; }
.foo:hover { fill: #7F7FFF; }

.bar { fill: #7F7F4C; stroke: #7F7F00; }
.bar:hover { fill: #FFFF7F; }

.sib-prev.box {
  stroke: #FF0000;
}

.sib-next.box {
  stroke: #00FF00;
}
```

```html
<svg width="260" height="196">
  <rect class="box foo" x="6" y="6" width="120" height="40" />
  <rect class="box bar" x="6" y="54" width="120" height="40" />
  <rect class="box foo" x="6" y="102" width="120" height="40" />
  <rect class="box bar" x="6" y="150" width="120" height="40" />
  
  <rect class="box bar" x="134" y="6" width="120" height="40" />
  <rect class="box foo" x="134" y="54" width="120" height="40" />
  <rect class="box bar" x="134" y="102" width="120" height="40" />
  <rect class="box foo" x="134" y="150" width="120" height="40" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you really need a javascript solution, go for the answers with javascript.

This answer, however, shows a simple non-JS solution using vanilla CSS. You'll see a button and a SVG square. By simply using CSS `:hover` and `:focus` on both `button` and `svg` the color of the square changes 4 times...

```css
/*
    CSS Selector Reference
    https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp
*/
svg       { fill: red; width: 100px  }
svg:hover { fill: purple }

button:hover + svg { fill: lime } /* + = immediate sibling selector */
button:focus + svg { fill: blue }
```

```html
<button>hover, click and unfocus me</button>
<svg viewbox="0 0 100 100"><rect width="100" height="100" x="0" y="0" /></svg>
```

Comment: Thank you, that's amazingly simple. I've added my main body, to the question, I think my problem is to do with sibling/parent child relationships? is the grouping causing issues?